# Can you use a variable value to specify a jquery object name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

I have:

```
if (!myObj.login_id) { 
    alert("The object for login_id does not exist.");
} else {
    alert("The object for login_id DOES exist. The value of the object is: " + myObj.login_id);
}
```

This is working properly. The object and it's value are defined already. However, I have multiple objects which are named after their ID attr. So, I try doing this (say for example this is a click event:

```
objtitle = $(this).attr('id'); // this is "login_id"

if (!myObj.objtitle) {
    alert("The object for "+objtitle+" does not exist.");   
} else {
    alert("The object for "+objtitle+" DOES exist. The value of the object is: " + myObj.objtitle);
}
```

Why does it stop working when I use a variable for the name of the object?

Comment: `if ( !myObj[ this.id ] ) { ...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use square brackets.

```
myObj[objtitle]
```

Comment: Just seeing how I can thank someone for helping me out on here. I clicked "this information is useful" and "this is your accepted answer"... thanks also to lonesomeday!

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of accessing an object's properties: the dot syntax and the square bracket syntax. These are called [member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). So the following two are equivalent:

```
obj.foo
obj['foo']
```

The dot syntax (the first one) is a literal name.  `obj.objtitle` therefore attempts to find a property called `objtitle`. If you have a variable containing the property name you want, you have to use the square bracket syntax.

```
myObj[objtitle]
```